Slate dashboard shareable link stopped working
I have a slate dashboard and the shareable link was working fine but now it has stopped. Any idea what could cause this to stop working?
Have not tried anything yet looking at previous versions to see what I can.
Thanks in advance

can you check that the link you've been sharing is the same as the link provided by the Share dialog?
What issues are you getting with the share link? What does it redirect to?
URLs that look like this (/slate/app/example-app?$view=lyIzd4vdKTE) are called "shareable views" and do not give people permission to open/view your application. However if someone does have permission to open your application, the "shareable view" link will open the app and pre-fill it with the same data as when the shareable view was created i.e. the input fields will have the same values.
The URL to actually share the application will look like this: /shares/links/n3rmrjn6okthw. And you can configure if the link only gives View access, Edit access, Owner access etc. via the UI.
Image of sharing UI

the published version is a/c 116 empty. like this.  https://luster.palantircloud.com/workspace/slate/app/bow-report/home      the shared link looks like this.....    https://luster.palantircloud.com/workspace/slate/app/bow-report?$view=cUUpP-MnXGw     but redirects back to home page no saved data. I have tried all 3 browsers

Ah I see. URLs like /slate/app/example-app?$view=lyIzd4vdKTE are called 'shareable views' - what they allow you to do with share a link to a Slate app, and when loaded, it will be pre-filled with the same data as when the shared view was created i.e. any input boxes you filled in etc.
This link will still not give permission to people to access the application if they don't have it. For that, you need to give them permission using the normal "Share" option that you can in the same menu.

The share link you want will look something like this: /shares/links/n3rmrjn6okthw

Sorry I think I miss spoke I do want the saved state link "shareable view" but I cannot save the state and reopen it myself. I am the owner of the dashboard. the saved state redirects back to home page.

Gotcha - this seems like it's a bug and that shareable views are not correctly loading the state - thanks for reporting this. I've identified what is causing the issue and a release should be made available by next week. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Note that shareable views don't work with multipage, they just work for variables and widgets on the main "home" page - what you can do it load values on that home page and then use "shared variables" to transfer the values over to the other pages.
Will also report back when the bug is fixed.

Great thanks so much for looking into this.

Hi @KevinThistle, we've released a fix and it should be available on your Foundry stack soon
